# Using R resources from an android jar file

Tags: android, jar, resources

This has been talked about a few times, with varying states of success but most of the answers I can find are several years in the past.

Essentially, I have an application which has moved to a point where isn't being shared with customers. Customers want to extend the application but we don't want them to have access to the original code -- protecting IP on all that.

The layouts, images, etc... well, we don't care about those as much, only the java code. I could easily compile the java code into a jar and distribute it, but that's only half the answer. The java code still references a whole pile of internal resources.

The scenario I'm working with is jar file contains the following:

In Jar file
- MyActivity extends Activity
  - onCreate() within MyActivity sets the contentView to an R-referenced layout from within the jar file.

In client application
- MyClientActivity extends MyActivity

When this is run, I get a ClassNotFoundException on MyClientActivity.

Things I've noticed:
- If I attach the jar code as a library, instead of a jar file, it works.
- If I remove the R reference within onCreate() in MyActivity and remake my jar file, it works.

So, obviously, as pointed earlier, the R references are dead/not accessible. The thing is, this *apparently* can work, no? If you create an Android application and look at the auto-included APIs, the android.jar file has an R file, with internal layouts/strings/etc... which are being references from within its code.

As others have said before, this seems like a very basic and obvious usage pattern. The fact that it seemingly doesn't work is mind boggling enough to lead one to believe that it does in fact work, it's just not done in an obvious way.

Has anyone ever actually gotten it to work?

Thanks a lot,

-Cord Awtry

Comment: What class is not found when it throws the ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: Oddly, it's the client project class... i.e., not the one in the library/jar file which is being extended.

Comment: Could you add some actual code, it's hard to imagine it all.

Comment: Ridcully, thanks for the interest. I've made a simple project to illustrate the issue. Below is a pastie with the two activities, from the client and lib, the lib layout and the exception. [Pastie](http://pastie.org/4868385). Again, it works great if the 'lib' is attached as a library, in which case it is compiled into the client code, but if you export the lib as a jar and attempt to use it, then the exception below is thrown.

Comment: And have you put the jar-file in the libs folder of the client application? And have you specified the LibClientActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml of the client-application? I don't think it has anything to do with the R class, as you don't even use it in the LibClientActivity.

Comment: Yes, the LibClientActivity activity is specified in the client manifest, as can be seen [here](http://pastie.org/4884895). My theory that it's the R class is that if I remove the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line from the MainActivity in jarred lib, it works just fine. Granted, it doesn't show a UI. I can happily send you the two projects, though I don't want to over-stay my welcome with your help. :)

Comment: As a followup to my own question, this ended up not working. I actually package the resources within the client app and use context.getResources().getIdentifier() to find the actual resources within the java library.