# using R in JAR file?

Tags: android, jar

I am working with a library as a JAR where i have added strings and sending the context of main Application to fetch string to register GCM.

This is my method in the JAR file:-

```
void registerGCM(Context context){

GCMLibrary.register(context, context.getString(R.string.c2dm_sender));

}
```

I have declared c2dm_sender in library and in my Application in Strings.

But i am getting this error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
```

I have seen this [Using R resources from an android jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653974/using-r-resources-from-an-android-jar-file) as a reference but not getting it resolved.

I am looking for the solution that R file of my Application is used and c2dm_sender to be used from there.

Comment: Please check that you are importing the correct R file. My Android environment has the habit of importing a default R file.

Comment: @EricTobias: i have imported a correct R file. If i use the library as a library project everything works well. but as i create its JAR it does not picks resource

Comment: Are you positive that the JAR contains the resource? If so, then I'd say this is a classical problem of correctly referencing the location of the file. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900154/classpath-resource-within-jar for more advice on the matter.

Comment: Yes i am sure JAR contains a resource.I have another project where this is working

Comment: Perfect. Than all you need to do is correctly determining the location of the resource. The link I provided should help.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code for that......

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.c2dm_sender);
```

Comment: used it but same problem.

Comment: where is your string ? in res/values or res/values-mdpi or with other dpi

Comment: I have single value folder and there i have strings.xml